# Tooltip on mouseover in JavaScript calendar

Tags: javascript

I want to make pregnancy calendar, for that I want do tooltip when mouse hover the days. I want to make 273 tooltips for first 273 days from current month. How can I do it?

Comment: We don't know which date picker you are using, what you mean by simply posting a question without having any html and proper information.
Make a fiddle then we could do something on it and give it.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a very good datepicker and they have tooltips along with other features to use!

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/

Then to use the `tooltip` all you have to do is this:

```
$('#DOM_Element').tooltip()
```